# Evaluate $\int x^2\log(1-x^2)dx$, and hence prove that $\frac1{1\cdot5}+\frac1{2\cdot7}+\frac1{3\cdot9}+...=\frac23\log2-\frac89$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int x^2\log(1-x^2)dx$, and hence prove that $\frac1{1\cdot5}+\frac1{2\cdot7}+\frac1{3\cdot9}+...=\frac23\log2-\frac89$

**My Attempt:**

Integrating by parts,

$$\log(1-x^2)\cdot\frac{x^3}3-\int\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{x^3}3dx\\=\frac{x^3}3\log(1-x^2)-\frac23\int\frac{1-x^4-1}{1-x^2}dx\\=\frac{x^3}3\log(1-x^2)-\frac23\int1+x^2-\frac1{1-x^2}dx\\=\frac{x^3}3(\log(1-x)+\log(1+x))-\frac23(x+\frac{x^3}3)+\frac13\log|\frac{1-x}{1+x}|+c\\=\frac{x^3-1}3\log(1-x)+\frac{x^3+1}3\log(1+x)-\frac23(x+\frac{x^3}3)+c$$

If we apply limits from $0$ to $1$, we get

$$\frac23\log2-\frac89,$$

which is the required RHS.

How to get the required LHS?

Comment: Just by looking at this, I'm assuming you need to use the power series $$\log\left(1-x^{2}\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(-x^{2}\right)^{n}}{n}$$ where the domain of convergence is $|x|^2 < 1$. It's just a thought, though.

Comment: @Accelerator thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Taylor series of $\log(1-t)$:
$$\log(1-t)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n,\qquad t\in[0,1),$$
we have
$$\int_0^1 x^2\log(1-x^2)dx=-\int_0^1x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}n\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_0^1x^{2+2n}\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(3+2n)},$$
which is exactly the required LHS (except for the minus sign). Here, the reason why we can interchange the summation and integration is the [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem), or that we can always integration a power series term by term, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration).

So, we have proven that
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(3+2n)}=\frac23\log2-\frac89,$$
which differs from the original problem by a minus sign. Indeed, the original problem is not correct. Clearly we have $\frac1{1\cdot5}+\frac1{2\cdot7}+\frac1{3\cdot9}+\cdots>0$, but $\frac23\log2-\frac89< \frac23-\frac89<0.$ Therefore, the right version is
$$\frac1{1\cdot5}+\frac1{2\cdot7}+\frac1{3\cdot9}+\cdots=\frac89-\frac23\log2.$$
[Wlofram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2Cn%5C%2840%292n%2B3%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) agrees with our computation.

Comment: Thank you. How can we account for the minus sign here?

Comment: @aarbee  It turns out that your original problem lost a minus sign. I've added the explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: @aarbee You're welcome. I'm glad to help :)